# Wildfly 10.0.0.Final duplicates contents of <jsp-config> <url-pattern> directive in web.xml

Tags: jsp, web.xml, wildfly-10

I have been successfully deploying an application on WildFly 8.2.1 and WildFly 9.0.2 versions with the following `<jsp-config>` directives in `web.xml` deployment descriptor:

```
<jsp-config>
<jsp-property-group>
<description>header and footer settings</description>
<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/view/*</url-pattern>
<url-pattern>/WEB-INF/error/*</url-pattern>
<include-prelude>/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf</include-prelude>
<include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>
</jsp-property-group>
</jsp-config>
```

This code fragment includes the contents of `/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf` at the beginning of each `.jsp` file and `<include-coda>/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf</include-coda>` at the end of each `.jsp` file that matches the `<url-pattern>`.

But when I try to deploy this application with the same deployment descriptor in WildFly 10.0.0.Final, the contents of `/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf` and `/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf` are included twice in each `.jsp` file that matches the `<url-pattern>`.

If I add another `<url-pattern>` line, then the contents of `/WEB-INF/jspf/header.jspf` and `/WEB-INF/jspf/footer.jspf` are included three times, and so on.

Any suggestion about this issue?

Is this a deployment descriptor issue or a configuration issue in the `standalone.xml` of WildFly 10.0.0.Final version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This a confirmed [bug](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFLY-6136) in WildFly 10.

[Fix](https://github.com/wildfly/wildfly/pull/8662) has been prepared and will be part of upcoming 10.1 release.